# Oracle error 43914 in CASE WHEN expression: arguments have undefined collation

Tags: sql, database, oracle, case-when

I want to know which is the difference between this query:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE 
WHERE CHAR_FIELD = CASE 
                      WHEN KEY_FIELD = 'Q' 
                      THEN 'M' 
                      ELSE 
                         CASE 
                            WHEN KEY_FIELD = 'T' 
                            THEN 'K'
                            ELSE CHAR_FIELD2 
                         END 
                   END;
```

And this:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE 
WHERE CHAR_FIELD = CASE 
                      WHEN KEY_FIELD = 'Q' 
                      THEN 'M' 
                      ELSE 
                         CASE 
                            WHEN KEY_FIELD <> 'T'
                            THEN CHAR_FIELD2 
                            ELSE 'K' 
                        END 
                   END;
```

I expect both queries to return same data in all cases but, first one gives me an ORA-43914 "unable to determine collation: arguments have undefined collation" error while second one works just fine.

I read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/nlspg/appendix-C-collation-derivation-and-determination-rules-for-SQL-operations.html#GUID-AFCE41ED-775B-4A00-AF38-C436776AE0C5) information about collation determination in Oracle but it's not clear to me how it works with case-when expression.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is when `KEY_FIELD` is `NULL`.  In that case, the second `CASE` always goes to the `ELSE` in both queries.

That said, I find the `CASE` expression overcomplicates the logic.  I prefer simpler boolean operations:

```
WHERE (CHAR_FIELD = 'M' AND KEY_FIELD = 'Q') OR
      (CHAR_FIELD = 'K' AND KEY_FIELD = 'T') OR
      (CHAR_FIELD = 'K' AND KEY_FIELD NOT IN ('Q', 'T'))
```

This doesn't actually handle `NULL` values in `KEY_FIELD`.  That would have to be handled explicitly.